# Division ring as a vector space over a subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a division ring and let $Z(R)$ be its center. Then clearly $Z(R)$ is a field. It is then claimed that $R$ forms a vector space over its center, but I can't see how that is so.

We know that by Lagrange theorem, $|R/Z(R)|=n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and so we can partition $R$ into $n$ cosets, with $Z(R)$ being one of them. So if $R$ a n-dimensional vector space over $Z(R)$, then each member of $R$ is a vector with $n$ entries, and each entry is a member of $Z(R)$.

But I don't quite see how such a vector space has the same set as $R$?

In other words, how can you possibly represent every element of the ring $R$ as a vector with $n$ entries over the field $Z(R)$?

Comment: "Vectors with $n$ entries" has nothing to do with the definition of a vector space...

Comment: A vector space $V$ over a field $F$ is an abelian group endowed with a scalar multiplication map $F \times V \to V$ satisfying certain properties. Here, $V =R$, $F = Z(R)$, and the scalar multiplication is induced by the restriction of the multiplication map $R \times R \to R$ to $Z(R) \times R \to R$.

Comment: I know the axioms for vector spaces. I'm just confused about what the vector space looks like for this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of what you are considering has anything to do with verifying that $R$ is a vector space over $Z(R)$.  To verify that, you just have to use the definition of a vector space.  That is, $R$ must have an addition operation and a scalar multiplication operation (with "scalars" being elements of $Z(R)$) which satisfy a certain list of axioms.  The addition is just the usual ring addition of $R$, and the scalar multiplication is just the usual ring multiplication of $R$, since elements of $Z(R)$ are also elements of $R$.  The vector space axioms then follow immediately from the ring axioms.

Comment: It's not.  What makes you think it is?

Comment: For instance, if $R=\mathbb{H}$, then $Z(R)=\mathbb{R}$, and $R/Z(R)$ is uncountable, but $\mathbb{H}$ has dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But doesn't every vector space have a dimension? Even if it is infinite?

Comment: Yes.  But there is no reason that dimension should be the same as the cardinality of $R/Z(R)$...

Comment: Thanks! So I guess each element $r\in R$ can be thought as a vector $r=1r$ where $1\in Z(R)$?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "can be thought as a vector".

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to consider elements of a vector space as column vectors. I know, it is pretty naive.

Comment: To do that you would first need to choose a basis.

Comment: “trying to consider elements of a vector space as column vectors”: don’t do that. Rather, you should just look at the definition of vector space, as sketched by @EricWofsey and Alex Wertheim above, and notice that the conditions are satisfied. Extreme example: verify for yourself that $\Bbb R$ is a vector space over $\Bbb Q$.